# External link open accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion

I see a lots of examples but I still don't get it !
I try to open an accordion panel on another page.

My goal:
When we click on a specific link on page A, we are redirected inside the accordion data-id='32' on page B.

My working url:www.mysite.ccc/page/?sub=32#milmedia
The url redirect to id 32 but is not opening the id 32.

```
<ul class="accordion">
<li class="accordion__item"><div class="underline-list__item js-accordion-open" data-id="30"><div class="underline-list__link">
<div class="underline-list__text"><h3>Title</h3><span class="accordion_button"><span class="accordion_button_icon"></span></span></div></div></div>
<div class="accordion__content js-accordion-content"><div class="wysiwyg">
my content
</div></div></li>

<li class="accordion__item"><div class="underline-list__item js-accordion-open" data-id="32"><div class="underline-list__link">
<div class="underline-list__text"><h3 id="milmedia">Title</h3><span class="accordion_button"><span class="accordion_button_icon"></span></span>    </div></div></div>
<div class="accordion__content js-accordion-content"><div class="wysiwyg">
my content
</div></div></li>

<li class="accordion__item"><div class="underline-list__item js-accordion-open" data-id="42"><div class="underline-list__link">
<div class="underline-list__text"><h3>Title</h3><span class="accordion_button"><span class="accordion_button_icon"></span></span></div></div></div>
<div class="accordion__content js-accordion-content"><div class="wysiwyg">
my content
</div></div></li>
</ul>
```

My jQuery attempt:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var check = location.hash;
  if (check == "milmedia") {
    $(window).load(function()
   {
    $('.js-accordion-open[data-id=32]').trigger('click');
   });
 }
 });

Using this version: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

** If I do that, it's working perfectly, but the "if" is missing
$(window).load(function()
 {
 $('.js-accordion-open[data-id=32]').trigger('click');
 });
```

Sorry for my bad english, I'm french !
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out !

```
 $(function(){
if (window.location.hash == "#dfse") {$('.js-accordion-open[data-id=33]').trigger('click');}
else if (window.location.hash == "#tyjh") {$('.js-accordion-open[data-id=32]').trigger('click');}
else if (window.location.hash == "#ngfc") {$('.js-accordion-open[data-id=31]').trigger('click');}
else {return false;}
});
```